# Where do I report 1042 S income and tax withheld on form 1040?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, f1-student-visa, form-1040

I am an F1 student and I am filing joint taxes with my husband, who is a resident alien. We are to fill form 1040.

As a non-resident alien when I file 1040-NR, there's space to report the fellowship income and federal tax withheld reported on 1042-S. But we don't have an equivalent space in form 1040. So where should I fill in the income and tax withheld reported on 1042-S on form 1040?

Answer (score 1):

Per the 1040 instructions (also downloadable in PDF, if you want to have or keep a copy or for anyone who finds this in the future, use the nav link at the top of the page to go up one level):

- Scholarship or fellowship income, if taxable, goes on [line 1 with a notation SCH](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#idm139798488470400) (sixth bullet). For details on whether and to what extent your grant is taxable, see [pub 970 ch 1](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p970#idm140609549099376). If and to the extent it is *not* taxable, don't report it at all.
- Withholding goes on [line 17](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1040gi#idm139798487435376). The *form* only identifies W-2 and 1099 as sources for withholding, but the instructions list several more including 1042-S.